# Date Comparison in jsp with data base

Tags: jsp, date, comparison

Iam new to jsp and using jsp and ms access.My problem is I have a date field (dd/mm/yy) format.I want to compare that date with current system date and I want to display all rows whose date value is less than 2 weeks as compare to system date

For example  date value contains the date 22/02/2014 and if sysdate(today) is 8/02/2014 it should display all the rows whose date value greater that 08/02/2014.

Comment: That has nothing to do with JSPs. Your controller, written in Java (as a servlet for example) should execute a SQL query that selects rows between 2 dates. The JSP should simply display the objects that have been retrieved by the query and stored in a request attribute by the controller.

Comment: I retrieved data using request.getParameter. Kindly suggest me how to compare this date with sysdate

Comment: I already suggested you: use a SQL query that retrieves the rows whoses date is between the two dates : `select id, name, date from mytable where date >= ? and date < ?`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..Actually my need is I want to display the rows, where date in that rows are only 2 weeks ahead of current date. Like a reminder it works